# WP Ajax on page load not working on bluehost but was working on Godaddy

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

**Let me explain the whole thing:**
I have form and on submit it generates graph on the result page. I am using html2canvas and jspdf to create pdf from the result page's section with id 'graphtopdf'. After that I am sending the data (base64_encode of the pdf) with WP AJAX to a function so that I can attach it with an email.

It is not working after the website has moved to bluehost from godaddy where it was working fine. I have no idea what is going on because there is no error or warning!!

Here is the code snippets:

```
jQuery(function($){
$("#headnote").css('display','block');
$("#footnote").css('display','block');
html2canvas($('#graphtopdf'), {
    allowTaint: true,
    taintTest: false,
    onrendered: function(canvas){
        $("#headnote").css('display','none');
        $("#footnote").css('display','none');
        var semail = $('#emailholder').val();
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        doc.addImage(canvas,'JPEG',2,10);
        var updf = btoa(doc.output());
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: log_data.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "ssr_form_sub",
                e: semail,
                s: updf
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
});
});

//functions.php file
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ssr_form_sub", "ssr_submit");
add_action("wp_ajax_ssr_form_sub", "ssr_submit");
function ssr_submit() {
 //wpmail code..
}
```

Can someone please guide me so that i can solve the issue.

Comment: Issues like this are commonly caused by mod_security rules. Have you checked with your host to see if your script is triggering their rules?

Comment: @BA_Webimax, I have found the problem! I don't know about mod_security rules but I'm sure the problem has something to do with bluehost security rules.. I think I will post the answer that may help somebody else!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay let me answer my own question because I know nobody can answer this properly without having similar situation!! May be this will be helpful to others. The problem was created by the JavaScript lib '[html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#available-options)'
It seems like bluehost doesn't like it's two options:

**allowTaint**  : Whether to allow cross-origin images to taint the canvas

**taintTest**   : Whether to test each image if it taints the canvas before drawing them

My problem has solved by removing these two options.